# Square problem in geometry

Tags: geometry

[image]

Need hints:
Length of the square is 5. How to correlate with these small square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the length of the smaller square is $a$ unit, the area $=a^2$ square unit,

$\implies$ the area of the larger square will be $9a^2$ square unit

$\implies$ the length of the larger square will be $\sqrt{9a^2}=3a$ unit

We have $a+3a=5$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Ratio of sides small:big=1:3 and small + big = 5

Answer (score 4):

Let $x$ side of smaller square then other square is $5-x$ because the biggest has side 5, from conditions we need to solve equation
$$9x^2=(5-x)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the side length of the larger square, and let $S$ be the side length of the smaller square.

The information we know is:
$$L+S=5\tag{1}$$
$$L^2=9S^2\tag{2}$$
Since both $L$ and $S$ are positive, equation $(2)$ can be safely converted to the statement
$$L=3S\tag{3}$$
by taking the square root of both sides. Use equation $(1)$ to express $L$ in terms of $S$, then plug into equation $(3)$. Solve for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How long is AB?
- What is the ratio of the sides of the two grey squares?
- How do you divide AB in this ratio?